# Adding a comment fill color in Excel using openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I'm creating Excel files using an R script. In the script, I want to add comments to several cells and then edit the style of these comments. So far, I have seen that I can use the `createStyle()` function to define the font color, font size, fill color etc. Then use the `createComment()` function to enter a text and apply this style. In the end, `writeComment()` is used to write the comment in the workbook in a specified cell. An example would be the following:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
s1 <- createStyle(fgFill="#FF5733")
c1 <- createComment(comment="This is a comment.", style=s1)
writeComment(wb, 1, col=1, row=2, comment=c1)
```

However, I have read in the documentation (and in the code on GitHub: https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/tree/master) that when adding a style to the comments, only the font related settings are copied, whereas the background color settings are only taken into account when using the `addStyle()` function to edit the cell, not the comment on that cell.

Therefore, the previous block of code gives the following content inside the `comments` variable of the workbook `wb`:

```
> wb$comments[[1]][[1]]
$ref
[1] "A2"

$author
[1] "admin"

$comment
[1] "This is a comment."

$style
[1] "<rPr><sz val=\"11\"/><color rgb=\"FF000000\"/><name val=\"Calibri\"/></rPr>"

$clientData
[1] "<x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Note\"><x:MoveWithCells/><x:SizeWithCells/><x:Anchor>1, 15, 0, 10, 2, 147, 5, 18</x:Anchor><x:AutoFill>False</x:AutoFill><x:Row>1</x:Row><x:Column>0</x:Column><x:Visible/></x:ClientData>"
```

As seen above, only the default font settings were saved (size 11, color black, font Calibri), but the background color was ignored.

My question is: is there a way to add the background color (fill) to the comments in Excel, using R and `openxlsx`? My ultimate goal is to add an image as the comment background (this possibility is available inside Excel), but for starters just changing the color would be nice.

Comment: That's not possible from the `writeComments()` command as it requires modification of the comments vml code. For details see [this PR](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/pull/870) for `openxlsx2`. (I wont add further styling options, because the entire functionality to style comments was removed in the Mac version of MS365 when Microsoft reworked comments with threads.)

Comment: @JanMarvin thanks for the reference! Do you think it would be possible to add a picture as a background to a comment using `openxlsx2`?

Comment: It is probably possible, you would have to create test files, then check how the images are stored there and try to reproduce this and finally integrate a function for this into the existing source code

Comment: I've added a pull request handling this to the development branch.